# Implement TaskExecutor in spring boot where Scheduling is already defined

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, scheduler, threadpoolexecutor, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have already define Scheduler in my spring boot project. Then I have to implement task scheduler which run thread pool. After I have added my scheduler task won't triggered. Even test case didn't run.

Scheduler Config Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig  {

    
}
```

Thread pool config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(500);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void smsProcessor(List<CampaignSchedulerData> campaignSchedulerDataList, int tenantId) throws InterruptedException {
  // file reader from AWS and send message accordingly 


}
```

Scheduler task

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron-expression.file-write}")
public void fileWriteScheduler() {
    LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    log.info("Run file Write Scheduler. Start time is :: {} ",
            DateTimeUtil.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(startDateTime));

    //add config scheduler time
    schedulerService.processFileWriteScheduler(startDateTime.minusMillis(file_write_SchedulerWaitingTime));
    LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    log.info("Run file Write Scheduler. ", "End time is :: {} ",
            DateTimeUtil.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(endDateTime), ". Time taken :: {} ", Period.fieldDifference(startDateTime, endDateTime));
}
```

I have tried to implement task scheduler then ApplicationSpringBoot class won't run.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
//Enable Annotations
public class BusinessTemplateApplication {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
When I add the task scheduler to the SchedulerConfig  class it will resolved

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig  {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(500);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
}
```